# Click button element in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, button, click

[HTML code for the button I want to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orWiK.png)

Can anyone please help me, I'm trying to tell selenium to click a button on a website I'm trying to automate. Ive attached a picture of the HTMl code that I want the Webdriver to click.
Can anyone tell me the best find element option to use to click the button.
Ive looked into Xpath but can't seem to get it working?
Thanks

```
<use xlink:href="#icon-menu-more" href="#icon-menu-more"></use>
```

So I was trying to grab the xPath from this line of code.
the Xpath is `/html/body/div/div[1]/header/nav/button[1]/span[1]/svg/use`
but then when trying to use `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`  i get an error saying unable to locate element.

Comment: _Ive looked into Xpath but can't seem to get it working_ Show us what you tried, and explain what happened.

Comment: What's your exact XPATH? What have you tried? Which line of HTML code are you grabbing the XPATH from?

Comment: What url is this as well?

Comment: So that's an absolute xpath, are there any changes in attributes from the root to element? If so, this will become invalid. If you're using a newer version of selenium you'd want to use ```driver.find_element(By.XPATH, " ")``` btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
driver.find_element_by_id('icon-menu-more')
```

this will help you to click the button

Other Options are

```
driver.find_element_by_name('name of element')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('class name of element')
driver.find_element_by_tag_name(tag name of element)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('css selector of element')
```